# Why does this padding not center content?

Tags: html, css

I understand that the padding is the space between your border and your innermost layer. In the following CSS, if I put the bottom padding to 40px, the content is not centered in the div. Why?

```css
div {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    color:blue;
    background-color:red;
    border:10px solid blue;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content area is still `40px` high (because that is the height you specified) and the text starts at the top of that.

Answer (score 2):

if you add a `line-height` and `text-align:center` it will `center` it vertically and horizontally

```css
div {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    color:blue;
    background-color:red;
    border:10px solid blue;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <div>hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't because you set `height` for your element, just remove it:

```css
div {
    width:40px;
    color:blue;
    background-color:red;
    border:10px solid blue;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>hello</div>
```